# Cannot get access to UI thread in WPF dll called from VB6 exe

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a VB6 exe that calls a WPF 4.0 dll.
In my WPF dll I have a background worker that needs to update the UI.
I cannot seem to get back to the UI thread because the Application.Current is null.

```
Application app = Application.Current;
if (app != null)
{
  Dispatcher disp = app.Dispatcher;
  if (disp != null)
  {
    if (!disp.CheckAccess())
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }
  }
}
```

I've also tried Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher but that also does not switch me to the UI thread.

Does anyone know how to switch to the UI thread in WPF when a VB6 exe calls a WPF dll?

Comment: Did you store Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher when you entered into the WPF dll from VB6, or were you trying it from the BackgroundWorker?

Comment: Thanks for tip; saving the Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher when I enter into the WPF dll from VB6 fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher when entering into the WPF side so that you can use it from the BackgroundWorker.